# I cannot open Software-center in 12.10

Tags: software-center

I cannot open the software center from a couple of days ago.
It is very estrange because when I throw the application from the console with `sudo` it is opened normally...

I paste the console text:

```
ramis@Ramis-Laptop:~$ software-center
2012-12-17 19:19:14,036 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-12-17 19:19:14,177 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-12-17 19:19:20,009 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2012-12-17 19:19:20,129 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2012-12-17 19:19:20,128 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2012-12-17 19:19:20,840 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2012-12-17 19:19:20,857 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Terminado (killed)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem , in Ubuntu 12.10i was not able to open the software centre.

The solution for my problem was as root level rights i just updated the apt-get:

`apt-get update`

after updating I opened the software centre and I was able to open.